# Difference between starting the process directly on machine and from remote desktop connection

Tags: opengl, 3d, mfc, rdp, ogre

I want to know the difference between application started directly on the machine and the application started using remote desktop connection.

Whether both the application are same or will have different privileges.

For example, i had an opengl based application  which take higher version of opengl 3 or 4 when started directly on the machine. But when i start the same application from remote desktop connection, it takes only base opengl version 1.1.

One more observation is:
We have a service application which will launch a graphics (OGRE based) application based on request. Request is set from client using web-socket communication.

When we start this service directly in a server, it works fine. But when this service is started from a RDP connection, the graphics application is crashing when user sends request after RDP connection is closed.

IT works if I keep the RDP connection on.

Answer (score 0):

It may loose the graphics driver when you are logged in through RDP.
If you look in the launch the Ogre 'setup' dialog when RDP is enabled it will not list the graphics card - but a different 'RDP driver'.

Also - when you log on\off it might 'reset' the device (since the RDP graphics driver is enabled\disabled) causing your window get loose the device, and then crash.

One way to get around all this - is to use a VNC (for example tightvnc), this does not cause the issues that standard RDP does, since it does not use the RDP graphics drivers and such.

Comment: Another way is to use the trick https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c8295ef8-3711-4576-9293-2c4965280165/opengl-and-remote-desktop?forum=winserverTS. A batch file disconnects the current RDP session and starts the application. If the application was started from the local session it has HW acceleration. After the application has started you can reconnect to RDP. The application should continue to use GPU.